# Javascript Web Audio API - AudioContext to base64

Tags: javascript, audio, base64, web-audio-api

in the project I'm working on, we have about 30 audio tracks where we apply filters and play the audio back. Originally this was done server-side, and returned a base64 string for each track, which I then loaded with `new Audio()`.

This worked well if you had fast internet speeds, but on slow speeds, it could take up to an hour for the tracks to be returned from the server, so now we're applying the filters client-side.

Applying the filters is no problem, but I'm trying not to rewrite my entire playback algorithm (it's much more involved than just pause, play, stop) and am wondering If I can encode an `AudioContext` to Base64.

I've tried creating a new `Audio` and passing the `AudioContext`, creating a new `Audio` and passing the `AudioBuffer` and something based on [this example](https://codepen.io/xewl/pen/NjyRJx?editors=0010). But none if it works and I cant find any examples of what I'm trying to do on the internet.

If someone could take a look at my code and help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

```
    var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
    var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "/path/to/audio", true);  
    request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    request.onload = function () {
        audioCtx.decodeAudioData(request.response, function (buffer) {
            source.buffer = buffer;

            // Apply filters to the audio

            // Here I would like to convert the audio to Base64
            callback(source);
        }, function (error) {
            console.error("decodeAudioData error", error);
        });
    };
    request.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to know exactly what you want from the snippet you give, but based on the snippet, you might be able to use an `OfflineAudioContext` if you know how long your audio files are.  The offline context will return an `AudioBuffer` which you can then use to get a base64-encoded audio result.